# How to get files out of Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator, sqlite-net

I'm completely new to Xamarin Forms and mobile development. I'm trying my luck with a test application following a tutorial from the internet to create an Android app.

The app is running so far and I can store data in a local SQLite database inside the Android emulator of Visual Studio 2017.

Now I'd like to inspect the created SQLite database on my windows host computer. Is there any way to get the created SQLite database out of the Android emulator?

I googled and found an article telling me to use the "Android Device Monitor" from Visual Studio, and inside this monitor I have a tab called "File Explorer" which seems to show me a file system looking kind of linux-y, so I guess it's the file system of the emulated Android.
But where do I find my SQLite database inside this "File Explorer"?

The database has been created inside the folder `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` and I read that I would find my database inside the folder "data", but I can't open this folder in the "File Explorer" of the "Android Device Monitor" with no apparent reason given to me.

Any help on that matter would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Causes:

you don't have the permission to read or write the db files

Solution:

1, Open up a terminal

2, cd [ANDROID_SDK_PATH] (for me on Windows cd D:\android-sdk)

3, cd platform-tools

4, adb shell (this works only if only one emulator is running)

5, cd data/data

6, adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"

7, adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data"

8, adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/[package_name]"

9, adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/[package_name]/databases"

10, adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/[package_name]/databases/*"

Comment: It worked up to step 5, in step 6 I got a `/system/bin/sh: adb: not found`. Do I really need to write `adb shell` again if I'm already inside this shell (from step 4)?